# Zabbix Action - How to use Default Field in Custom Script

Tags: python, api, monitoring, alarm, zabbix

I am making some script in python which is run by Zabbix Action. 
I want to add value in 
Default subject and Default message in Action fields and then use this values in my script. So I am running script and forward all needed macros in script parameters like:

`python /path/script.py -A "{HOST.NAME}" -B "{ALERT.MESSAGE}" -C "{ALERT.SUBJECT}"`

and i can get only HOST.NAME value, for others I get only macros name but no value

Have you any idea where is the problem? Those macros are unavailable using by Custom scripts?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqkFM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research & testing myself, it seems as if **these Alert macros are indeed not available in a custom script operation.**<sup>1</sup>

You have two options for a workaround:

---

**If you need to be able to execute this script on the host itself, the quick option is to simply replace the macro with the actual text of your subject & alert names.** Some testing is definitely necessary to make sure it will work with your environment, and it's not the most elegant solution, but something like this may well work with little extra effort:

```
python /path/script.py -A "{HOST.NAME}" -B "Problem: {EVENT.NAME}" -C "Problem started at {EVENT.TIME} on {EVENT.DATE}
Problem name: {EVENT.NAME}
Host: {HOST.NAME}
Severity: {EVENT.SEVERITY}

Original problem ID: {EVENT.ID}
{TRIGGER.URL}"
```

Verifying of course that e.g. the newlines do not break your custom script in your environment.
It doesn't look pretty but it may well be the easiest option.

---

**If you can run the command on any host, the nicer option is to create a new Media type**, which will let you use these variables and may even make adding this script to other hosts much easier. These macros can definitely be used as part of a custom Media type (see [Zabbix Documentation - Media Types)](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/notifications/media/script) which can include custom scripts.

You'll need to make a bash or similar script file for the **Zabbix server** to run (which means doing anything on a host outside the Zabbix server itself is going to be more difficult, but not impossible).

Once the media type is setup, as a bit of a workaround (not ideal, of course) you'll need a [user](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/config/users_and_usergroups/user) to 'send' to; assigning that media type to the user and then 'sending' the alert to the user with that media type should execute your script with the macros just like executing the custom command.

<sup>1: While I did do my own testing on this, I couldn't found any documentation which specifically *states* that these macros aren't supported in this case, and they definitely look like they *should* be - more than happy to edit/revoke this answer if anyone can find documentation that confirms or denies this.</sup>

Comment: thank you for your help! I have tried several ways but always same result. It looks like those macros are not available in custom scripts. Media Types script is usless for me. I will do my task with other way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I should also explain how it works now, so I did sth like:

```
python /path/script.py -A "{HOST.NAME}" -B "Problem: {EVENT.NAME}" -C "Problem started at {EVENT.TIME} on {EVENT.DATE}
Problem name: {EVENT.NAME}
Host: {HOST.NAME}
Severity: {EVENT.SEVERITY}

Original problem ID: {EVENT.ID}
{TRIGGER.URL}"
```

works for me :)